# How to populate objects of derived class with data members into a pointer array of base class

Tags: c++, arrays, polymorphism

When i try to output a material of type string of class 'Brakes' using polymorphism, it doesn't print correctly. I believe the problem has to do with me instantiating a new derived object. How do I populate a derived object with data members into an array of pointers of the base class in C++? Sorry if the format for the code is wrong rr if I didn't give enough information, it is my first time here.

in main():

`Parts *partsList = new Parts[arrayCount];`

function call:

```
populateArrayBrakes(&partsList,tokens,element);
```

function to populate the array with data:

```
void populateArrayBrakes(Parts *partsList[], string tokens[], int element){
        partsList[element] = new Brakes(tokens[1],tokens[2]...);
}
```

but for some reason when I output using polymorphism, there are spaces in the output and the materials are wrong (the first material is supposed to be "Synthetic Blend"):

```
brakes material: 1 Organic
brakes material: 2 Organic
brakes material: 3 Organic
brakes material: 4 Ceramic
brakes material: 5 Ceramic
brakes material: 6 Ceramic
brakes material: 7 Ceramic
brakes material: 8 Ceramic
brakes material: 9
brakes material: 10 Ceramic
brakes material: 11 Carbon Metallic
brakes material: 12
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 1.425 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`partsList` in `main` is a pointer to an array of `Parts`.

`populateArrayBrakes` populates an array of `Parts *` (pointers to parts).

Your use of `&parts` will results in Undefined Behavior because any access in `populateArrayBrakes` of `parts[element]` where element is not 0 will be out of bounds.

What you want is to declare `partsList` as a pointer array,

```
Parts **partsList = new Parts *[arrayCount];
```

However, use of raw pointers should be avoided and you should be using `std::vector` and smart pointers.